# Multiple inheritance. How to access member function of 1 Parent class to another parent class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have class C and it is inheriting from Class A and Class B.
Is it possible for class A to access Class B function( eg fun1() ) using this inheritance. A and B are both independent class and fun1() is only in class B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not strictly through inheritance. Although A and B are parents of C, A and B have no relationship and no way to access eachother.

It is possible through inheritance and polimorphism, then class A have a virtual method that C implements calling the function in B, like this:

```
class A {
public:
  b get_b() { return do_get_b(); }
private:
  virtual do_get_b() = 0;
};

class B {
public:
  b some_b;
};   

class C : public A, public B {
private:
  virtual do_get_b() {return some_b;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great ans. But i Didnt understood clearly. Inside class B what "b some_b" means. Y inside class A "b get_b()" implemented.

Comment: b some_b is a member variable named "some_b" of the type b

Answer (score 2):

You could check with dynamic_cast to see if your object of A is really a object of C, and thereby of B

```
void A::foo()
{
    B* pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(this);
    if (pB) pB->bar();
}
```

But if A and B are really independent of one another it is probably better to find a different solution.

Comment: This is called a side-cast. Reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast, explanation point 5.b. Note that for this to work, B has to be a `public` base class of C.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is possible. [An example how to achieve this.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10)

That example applies to a diamond hierarchy, which is a bit more complicated than yours. In your terms, ClassA and ClassB should be derived from class Base, ClassC is derived from ClassA and ClassB.

Comment: Here I dont have any Base calss inherited by class A and Class B. In this case is it possible to access Class B fun from Class A

Comment: You may consider adding Base class